# Tensorflow and Tensorflow-Probability NotFoundError: No algorithm Worked! [Op:Conv2D]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using tensorflow version 2.4.1 and tensorflow-probability 0.12.1

I'm trying to implement a mixture density network that takes 2D Images and converts them to a density estimating a one dimensional output, with a regularizing distribution on the output distribution to penalize for straying to much from a prior distribution.

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf
tfd = tfp.distributions
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Input, Dropout
import numpy as np

data_x = np.random.normal(size(100,32,14,1))
data_y = np.random.normal(size=(100,4))
```

I'm implementing the model as an inherited class:

```
@tf.function
def nnelu(input):
    """ Computes the Non-Negative Exponential Linear Unit"""
    return tf.add(tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32), tf.nn.elu(input))

class BNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_components=5,regularizing_distribution=None):
        super(BNN, self).__init__()
        self.num_components = num_components
        self.regularizer = regularizing_distribution
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(16,
                            (3,3),
                            activation='relu',
                            padding='same',
                            name='convolution_1')
        self.dropout1 = Dropout(.5)
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(32,
                            (3,3),
                            activation='relu',
                            padding='same',
                            name='convolution_2')
        self.dropout2 = Dropout(.5)
        self.conv3 = Conv2D(64,
                            (3,3),
                            activation='relu',
                            padding='same',
                            name='convolution_3')
        self.dropout3 = Dropout(.5)
        self.dense = Dense(32,activation='relu',name='dense_layer')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.mu = Dense(self.num_components,name='mixture_means',activation='linear')
        self.sigma = Dense(self.num_components,name='mixture_std',activation=nnelu)
        self.p = Dense(self.num_components,name='mixing_weights',activation='softmax')
        self.reg = Dense(3,name='regularizers',activation='softmax')
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs_, outputs = inputs
        conv1 = self.conv1(inputs_)
        dropout1 = self.dropout1(conv1)
        conv2 = self.conv2(dropout1)
        dropout2 = self.dropout2(conv2)
        conv3 = self.conv3(dropout2)
        dropout3 = self.dropout3(conv3)
        dense = self.dense(dropout3)
        flatten = self.flatten(dense)
        alpha = self.p(flatten)
        params = [self.mu(flatten),self.sigma(flatten),alpha]
        mixture = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(make_distribution_fn=lambda params:tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
                mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(probs=params[2]),
                components_distribution=tfd.Normal(
                loc=params[0],       
                scale=params[1]
                )
            ),
            activity_regularizer=tfp.layers.KLDivergenceRegularizer(distribution_b=self.regularizer,
                                                                    use_exact_kl=False,
                                                                    test_points_reduce_axis=(),
                                                                    test_points_fn=tf.convert_to_tensor,
                                                                    weight=None) 
            )(params)
        regularizer_alpha = self.reg(flatten)
        return mixture.log_prob(outputs), mixture.mean(), regularizer_alpha, alpha
```

I'm leaving the loss function and metric out, because the problem happens at the predict step.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model

input_x = Input(shape=(32,14,1)) #input X values / grid
input_y = Input(shape=(1,)) #input Y values / true values from observation

outputs = BNN(5, regularizing_distribution)([input_x,input_y])
model = Model(inputs=[input_x,input_y],outputs=outputs)
```

The error happens in the call and predict steps. If I do `model([data_x,data_y[:,0]])` or `model.predict([data_x,data_y[:,0]])` I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-ed6305fb6a12> in <module>
----> 1 model([data_x,data_y])

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1010         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1011             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1012           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1013 
   1014         if self._activity_regularizer:

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    422         a list of tensors if there are more than one outputs.
    423     """
--> 424     return self._run_internal_graph(
    425         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    426 

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
    558 
    559         args, kwargs = node.map_arguments(tensor_dict)
--> 560         outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    561 
    562         # Update tensor_dict.

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1010         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1011             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1012           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1013 
   1014         if self._activity_regularizer:

<ipython-input-138-b362925fd379> in call(self, inputs)
     39     def call(self, inputs):
     40         inputs_, outputs = inputs
---> 41         conv1 = self.conv1(inputs_)
     42         dropout1 = self.dropout1(conv1)
     43         conv2 = self.conv2(dropout1)

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1010         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1011             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1012           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1013 
   1014         if self._activity_regularizer:

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py in call(self, inputs)
    246       inputs = array_ops.pad(inputs, self._compute_causal_padding(inputs))
    247 
--> 248     outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    249 
    250     if self.use_bias:

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in convolution_v2(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name)
   1011     dilations=None,
   1012     name=None):
-> 1013   return convolution_internal(
   1014       input,  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
   1015       filters,

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in convolution_internal(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name, call_from_convolution, num_spatial_dims)
   1141         op = conv1d
   1142 
-> 1143       return op(
   1144           input,
   1145           filters,

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in _conv2d_expanded_batch(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name)
   2595     # We avoid calling squeeze_batch_dims to reduce extra python function
   2596     # call slowdown in eager mode.  This branch doesn't require reshapes.
-> 2597     return gen_nn_ops.conv2d(
   2598         input,
   2599         filter=filters,

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, explicit_paddings, data_format, dilations, name)
    930       return _result
    931     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 932       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
    933     except _core._FallbackException:
    934       pass

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6860   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6861   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6862   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6863   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6864 

/hpc/apps/pyhpc/dist/conda/x86_64/envs/cuda-11.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

NotFoundError: No algorithm worked! [Op:Conv2D]
```

This error is kind of arcane for me, and the reason it's especially confusing is that when implemented as a layer class and implemented within a layer class I can use model.fit, but not model.predict, but with the model class I can't use either.

I've tried selecting out components of the model, reducing it so that the outputs aren't passed in as input; in case the list unpacking was where the code broken down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That could help https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43174#issuecomment-691657692